# Character-level embeddings in python

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, spacy

I'm working on an NLP task that requires the use of character level embeddings, and I've been trying to use [Spacy](https://spacy.io/). However, it seems that spacy uses word-level embeddings for the word vectors, and I need character-level embeddings. The only character-level embedding library I've been able to find is [chars2vec](https://github.com/IntuitionEngineeringTeam/chars2vec) which does not seem well maintained. Is there a way to get character-level embeddings with either spacy or a more popular package than chars2vec?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/flairNLP/flair or https://fasttext.cc

Answer (score 0):

No - There is no way to get character level embeddings for SpaCy.

One option for character level embeddings is the [flair package](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair) which implements [Contextual String Embeddings for Sequence Labeling](https://aclanthology.org/C18-1139/).